# Problem converting 2 calls to async function so i can use Async await

Tags: node.js

As i am converting my code to Async Await i need to convert my functions to async but i am having trouble with 2. First one is a straight forward function to get a hash from my file.

```
const getHash = async (file_to_hash) =>
{
md5File(file_to_hash,(err, hash) => 
{
    if (err) throw err
    return hash

}
)}
```

and when i call it via

```
 const hash2 = await fh.getHash(newPath +'\\' + origFile.recordset[0].upload_id  + '.' + origFile.recordset[0].orig_file_type)
```

i get

```
const hash2 = await fh.getHash(newPath +'\\' + origFile.recordset[0].upload_id  + '.' + origFile.recordset[0].orig_file_type)
                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

i am using 'md5-file'

The other function which i have is to check if file exists and if delete it

```
const deleteFile = async (path) => {
fs.exists(path, function(exists) {
    if(exists) {
      fs.unlink(path)
      return true

   } else {
 return false
   }
  })
}
```

when calling it i get the folowing error

```
var delSuccess = await fh.deleteFile(tmpFile)    
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
```

Comment: You should probably read up on [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Plopping a callback-style asynchronous call into an `async` function is not going to work. Also don't check if a file exists and expect `unlink()` to succeed without errors. That causes a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

Answer (score -1):

async functions should return a promise.

If your code is not going to return a promise, you will need to wrap it in a promise.

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // write your non async code here
    // resolve() or reject()
  })
}
```

If your code returns a promise call, just return it with await.

```
const deleteFile = async (path) => {
  return await fs.exists(path);
}
```

Or sometimes you might want to return a promise from a callback,

```
const deleteFile = async (path) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.exists(path, function(exists) {
      if(exists) {
        await fs.unlink(path)
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(false); // or you can reject
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: if `fs.exists` already returns a `Promise`, you don't need to `return await`, nor wrap it in an `async` function. Also, doing `return await` is almost always a bad idea. Just return the `Promise` itself and let calling code `await` it.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to wrap above code inside a async function, because await is valid inside async. Like,

```
async function_name()=> {
    try{
          let hash2 = await fh.deleteFile(newPath +'\\' + 
                      origFile.recordset[0].upload_id  + '.' + origFile.recordset[0].orig_file_type)
    } catch(err){
          console.log('Error is: ', err);
    }
 }
```